# jstat : -gccapacity output

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jstat

As per [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) : -gccapacity shows :

**NGCMX** : Maximum new generation capacity (KB).

**NGC** :   Current new generation capacity (KB).

Is NGC shows currently **free** new generation capacity or currently **used** new generation capacity.

Comment: my question is about NGC output param.What does it signifies ?

Comment: it is requested to help.If any confusion, please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NGC shows how much the capacity of the new generation is right now.

NGC is a value between NGCMN and NGCMX. Part of the NGC may be used or may be free, and that is not indicated. It only indicates the current size of the new generation.